# Albergar una página HTML5 en un iframe de una página HTML4

Tags: html, html5, iframe

Tengo una página escrita en HTML4 y dentro de ella un `iframe` que apunta a una página HTML5. El resultado es que funciona perfectamente. No obstante me han dicho que esto no es recomendable. ¿Por qué es eso? ¿Puede esto tener alguna consecuencia negativa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El resultado funciona correctamente porque el contenido del `iframe` puede ser independiente del contenedor. La página del `iframe` no tiene por qué tener la misma especificación que la página que la contiene porque el navegador las tratará de manera independiente (aunque no tienen por qué serlo).

Puede tener un impacto "negativo" en diferentes ámbitos:

- SEO: los motores de búsqueda antes no procesaban el contenido del `iframe`, ahora sí lo hacen, pero su contenido no se indexaría con tu página al ser independiente.
- Enlaces: Es difícil hacer enlaces internos al contenido del `iframe`, se podría conseguir con algo de JavaScript, pero no sería algo "nativo" y fácil.
- Depuración: complican la depuración si hay errores - ¿ocurrió en el contenedor o en la página embebida? Aunque las herramientas de desarrollador de los navegadores ayudan con esto.
- Pueden ser un síntoma de mala arquitectura: muchas veces que he visto gente usando `iframe` fue más por "simplificarse" la vida en lugar de usar otros métodos alternativos que podrían ser más convenientes como AJAX (y me imagino que por aquí va lo que te han dicho).

Eso no quiere decir que no debas usar `iframe`. Hay casos en los que está justificado y es recomendable. Como en todo, va a depender el uso (y abuso) que se realice de los mismos.